# Auto Orientation Stopped Working

Tags: orientation

A few weeks ago, my Lumia 920 no longer was orienting the display when I turn it. This is in all my apps including viewing pictures and browsing. So now everything is always in portrait view and I can't get landscape view. I don't think I dropped or damaged my phone in any way.

Is this a problem with an internal sensor or might it be a setting that I don't know about? Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 1020 did the same thing. I turned it off completely then turned it back on and it works fine now.

Comment: Well, I'll be darned. I was sure I tried that, but I guess I hadn't. Thanks for answering. Everybody should turn off their phone every so often to clean out its cobwebs.